# Image Flickering only in Firefox

Tags: firefox, flicker

I have a popop on my page with cross button image.
When I open the popup for the first time everything is fine.
But when I close the popup and open it again, the cross button image flickers.
How can I Fix this.
I am facing this problem only in firefox. Are there any configuration settings which i need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. A button click function was written twice because of which the popup was loading twice and the image flickering happened.